# php - enable elements if not empty when retrieve value from database

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is the whole code i'm working on.

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Edit a Contract </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    ID: <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE id = $id";
            $result = $con->query($sql);
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $client_type = $row['client_type'];
        ?>

    <label for = "client1">
    <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client1" value="Division" <?php echo ($client_type == 'Division')? "checked" : "" ?> onclick="toggleDivision()"/> Division
    </label>
    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
    <label for ="client2">
    <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client2" value="External" <?php echo ($client_type == 'External')? "checked" : "" ?> onclick="toggleExternal()"/> External
    </label>
    &nbsp 
    <input type="text" id="extText" name="client_details2" value="<?php echo $row['client_details']; ?>" /> 
    <br><br>

    <div id="division">
        Division:
        <select  id="mySelect" name="client_details" onclick="enableTextbox()" disabled>
            <option value="Choose" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Choose' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Choose Division...</option>
            <option value="Distribution" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Distribution' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Distribution</option>
            <option value="Transmission" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Transmission' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Transmission</option>
            <option value="Generation" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Generation' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Generation</option>
            <option value="Procument" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Procument' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Procument</option>
            <option value="Other" <?php echo $row['client_details'] == 'Other' ? "selected" : ""; ?> />Others</option>
        </select>   
        <br><br>
        Others:<input type="text" id="otherTxt" name="client_details1" value="<?php echo $row['client_details']; ?>"  disabled />
        <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>     

<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleExternal() {
    document.getElementById("extText").disabled = false;

    var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
    for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
        divis_el.children[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
function toggleDivision() {
    document.getElementById("extText").disabled = true;
    var val = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
    var divis_el = document.getElementById("division");
    for (var i = 0; i < divis_el.children.length; i++) {
        divis_el.children[i].disabled = false;
        divis_el.children[5].disabled = true;
    }
}

function enableTextbox() {
var val = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
if (val == 0 || val == 1 ||val == 2 ||val == 3 ||val == 4) { document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = true}
if (val == 5) { document.getElementById("otherTxt").disabled = false; }
}
</script>   

</body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$client_type = isset($_POST ['client_type']) ? $_POST['client_type'] :null;
$client_details = isset($_POST ['client_details']) ? $_POST['client_details'] :null;

if($client_type == 'Division'){
$client_details = isset($_POST ['client_details1']) ? $_POST['client_details1'] :null;
$client_details = isset($_POST ['client_details']) ? $_POST['client_details'] :null;
} else {
$client_details = isset($_POST ['client_details2']) ? $_POST['client_details2'] :null;
}

if($client_details == 'Other') {
    $client_details = isset($_POST ['client_details1']) ? $_POST['client_details1'] :null;
} 
$query = "UPDATE contracts set client_type = '$client_type',`client_details` = '$client_details' WHERE `id` = '$id'";
if ($con->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br><br> Updated successfully <br>";
    echo $query;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
$con->close();                                 
}
?>
```

But I want the elements enabled automatically when the user go to the edit form without having to click the radio button again just to enable it again.

Something like for example this line of code.

```
 <input type="radio" name="client_type" id = "client1" value="Division" <?php echo ($client_type == 'Division')? "checked" : "" ?>  <?php if($client_type == 'External'){ echo 'disabled="disabled"';} ?> onclick="toggleDivision()"/> Division
```

When I try to run this line of code, it still works the same nothing different.

Are there any alternatives or examples to have the elements enabled when values are retrieved from the database?

Comment: "&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp...." - oh dear - did your keyboard get stuck?

Comment: The correct way to prevent sql injection is to use the combination of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding".

Comment: To debug your issue you will have to check what is actually contained in that `$row` you retrieve from the database.

Comment: all the `$row`s?

Comment: You only fetch one single `$row`. Reason why I ask is: you should tripple check if the element _really_ is called `client_type` and the values _really_ are `Division` or `External`. I bet something is off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using ajax. Ajax will make it live. Use ajax with php to make it live. Read more about it here : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Ajax is a javascript library like query.